# How to fix dead lock in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deadlock

I got following issue while running below code

```
Transaction (Process ID 54) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. Entity framework

     
  string[] to = new string[] { "A", "B" };
            Parallel.ForEach(to, code =>
            {
                DeleteHouses(code);
            });


private static void DeleteHouses(string code)
        {
            using var ctx = new BloggingContext();
            using var trans = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            var todel = ctx.dbsHouses.Where(d => d.Code == code).ToList();
            if (todel != null)
            {
                ctx.dbsHouses.RemoveRange(todel);
                ctx.SaveChanges();//Exception 
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
```

I tried Read Read Uncommitted IsolationLevel and using
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");

But none of them working for me

Comment: You don't need transaction here, is it your actual code? Do you have anything else running that uses/modifies the same database?

Comment: Don't do it in parallel. That's asking for trouble. Certainly don't use `READ UNCOMMITTED` without exactly knowing what you're doing, which usually means: don't use it.

Comment: Hi @nikita-chayka This is not my actual code .I created one sample in Entityframework

Comment: So does this exact code has the same problem?

Comment: Nops. I am facing the deadlock exactly same in the following url

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162724/why-does-a-select-query-require-an-ix-lock
But i couldn't replicate this type of lock in my sample solution.

Comment: Without your actual code that does have a deadlock and more details regarding usage of the database - I'm afraid that's impossible to help you. The only thing we could say here is that this particular code you provided should work, and you don't need any transactions here at all, specially not "Read Uncommitted" as specified by @GertArnold. And it has nothing to do with EF by itself, if you think so... just in case